# Is it possible to indicate an angle to a point marker symbol from field without using representation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography

Is it possible to indicate an angle to a point marker symbol automatically from data from a field without using [Representation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000004m000000) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this is described in the help page **[Creating marker symbols](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s600000002000000)** in the section titled **[Working with marker angles](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s600000002000000)** where it starts by saying:

> To rotate marker symbols individually based on the value of a field in
>   the point layer's attribute table click **Layer Properties dialog box >
>   Symbology tab > Advanced > Rotation**. On the **Rotate** dialog box, the
>   **Rotate Points by Angle in this field** specifies the field that holds
>   angular values and the **Rotation Style** controls the origin and
>   direction of rotation.